# Как поменять цвет закладок и общий фон браузера Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Как поменять цвет закладок и общий фон браузера Google Chrome? Не тему, а именно фон браузера и закладок!!!
При замене темы, цвет вкладок НЕ МЕНЯЕТСЯ!!!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь специальным расширением  [Theme Creator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/theme-creator/akpelnjfckgfiplcikojhomllgombffc?hl=ru) или [здесь](https://www.themebeta.com/chrome-theme-creator-online.html#)

Comment: Mi agradecimiento, amigo! Просто выручил!

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.